# Accessing a variable in a generic Node class from a specific Node variable...?

Tags: java, generics, binary-search-tree

I have implemented a generic Binary Search Tree class that has a nested node class that looks like this:

```
public class BST<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Iterable<E> {

protected class Node {
    E data;
    Node leftChild;
    Node rightChild;
    int depth;

    public Node(E data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.leftChild = null;
        this.rightChild = null;
        this.depth = 0;
    }

    public int getDepth(){
        return this.depth;
    }

    public void setDepth(int depth){
        this.depth = depth;
    }
}

protected Node root;

//methods are implemented past this point
```

I also have a `MazeNode` object class that stores lifepoints and a label (just a letter):

```
public class MazeNode implements Comparable<MazeNode>{
private String label; // label of the node
private int lifePoints; // number of possible life points our hero can collect at this maze node

public MazeNode(String label, int lifePoints) {
    this.label = label;
    this.lifePoints = lifePoints;
}

public String getLabel() {
    return label;
}

public int getLifePoints() {
    return lifePoints;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(MazeNode o) {
   return this.getLabel().compareTo(o.getLabel());
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return this.getLabel();
}
```

}

Here is my `Maze` class that does the iterating and finds a path down to the leaf nodes where my Hero has enough lifepoints to get down to the leaf node:

```
public class Maze extends BST<MazeNode> {

private int maxDepth = 0;

public void play(Hero hero) {
    Iterator<MazeNode> pre1 = this.preOrderIterator();
    Iterator<MazeNode> pre2 = this.preOrderIterator();
    int maxDepth = 0;

    while (pre1.hasNext()) {
        MazeNode node = pre1.next();
        if (node.leftChild == null && node.rightChild == null) {
            int x = node.getDepth();
            if (maxDepth < x) {
                maxDepth = x;
            }
        }

        Stack<MazeNode> stack = new Stack<MazeNode>();
        node = pre2.next();
        while (pre2.hasNext()) {
            if (node.leftChild == null && node.rightChild == null) {
                int y = node.getDepth();
                if (y == maxDepth && hero.getLives() >= 0) {
                    System.out.println(stack.toArray());
                    while (node != stack.peek().leftChild || node != stack.peek().rightChild) {
                        stack.pop();
                        hero.editLife(-(node.getLifePoints()));
                    }
                } else if (y < maxDepth) {
                    while (node != stack.peek().leftChild || node != stack.peek().rightChild) {
                        stack.pop();
                        hero.editLife(-(node.getLifePoints()));
                    }
                }
            } else {
                stack.push(node);
                hero.editLife(node.getLifePoints());
            }
            node = pre2.next();
        }

    }
}
```

}
The goal of the project is, given a `BST` with a label and `lifePoints` at each node, find all the paths in which my hero can exit from the highest depth nodes, but my hero can only exit if he has enough life points to get to the bottom.

The issue in my `play()` method is that my node variable is of type `MazeNode` and as a result cannot access the `leftChild`, `rightChild`, and depth fields that are in my BST Node class. How can I make it so it can? I wrote the logic out just for context, but obviously it does not work because my node variable cannot access the aforementioned data. **I must keep the BST Node class of type node, I cannot make it generic. I also cannot make a new class to try and put them together.**

I've tried type casting, but I'm still new to generics so I haven't really been able to figure it out. As I mentioned, I'm not allowed to make a new class or change my BST Node to a generic type.

Comment: Your BST consists of nodes, and each node holds a value - that's what the E is about. In your getup, you have a BST consisting of Node objects, and each Node object holds values, and those values are of type MazeNode. This is confusing - you have 2 __completely different__ concepts both called 'nodes'. Step 1 is to rename MazeNode to anything else.

Comment: It looks like the problem is in `preOrderIterator` which you haven’t shown. It must return `Iterator<E>` instead of `Iterator<Node>`

Comment: @TimMoore project specifications require my Iterator to be generic.